# How to integrate bootsfaces and jsf on glassfish server?

Tags: glassfish, jsf-2.2, bootsfaces

The boots faces  won't show when i run the xhtml page. I just added the jars from the website to libraries, am I missing something? Should I change some XML file or something. I know it works on Tomee but i have to use Glassfish for this.

Comment: in your xhtml file have you added the bootsfaces namespace?  for example `<ui:composition xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui" ...>`.  usually i use maven to handle dependencies so i don't have to add them to the lib folder.  you just list the dependency in the pom.xml in your project root

Comment: @MitchBroadhead i have added the dependency in pom.xml and namespaces like they explained on their site. The page shows and the jpa side works but the bootstrap isn't working. Thanks for answering by the way!

Comment: could you provide some code samples? for example excerpts from your xhtml file and your backing bean.  and maybe the pom.xml.  which version of bootsfaces are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are nasty bugs in the Glassfish implementation. Maybe you've run into one of them. Have a look at this article of mine [describing how to run BootsFaces on a Glassfish server](https://www.beyondjava.net/running-bootsfaces-on-glassfish-or-payara).